# Coffeescript to iterate through an array of words on a page?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I've got an array of words I want to iterate through on a page, making the existing word rotate out, and a new word rotate in.

I'm using [animate.css](http://daneden.me/animate/) to handle the animations via adding and removing a class.

The initial div has an entrance class `.rotateIn` on it, and so animates on page render. It also has a `.animated` class on it, which must be present in order for the animation to be triggered.

After a two second delay, I add the exit animation class `.rotateOut`, then remove the entrance class, which then triggers the exit animation. At this point, the div is hidden.

I change the text, then add the entrance class, then remove the exit class, triggering the entrance animation.

Once I hit the last word in the array, the function stops.

What's the best way to write this in coffeescript so that I can tweak the timings between entrance and exit?

**EDIT:** here's some basic javascript code showing what I'm trying to do. I'd like to rewrite this so that I can set an array of words `['foo', 'bar']` rather than the fragile PITA way below.

```
var $adj = $('#adjectives');

setTimeout(function() {
$adj.addClass('rotateOut');
setTimeout(function() {
    $adj.removeClass('rotateIn');
    setTimeout(function() {
        $adj.text('foo');
        $adj.addClass('rotateIn');
        setTimeout(function() {
            $adj.removeClass('rotateOut');
            setTimeout(function() {
                $adj.addClass('rotateOut');
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $adj.removeClass('rotateIn');
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $adj.text('bar');
                        $adj.addClass('rotateIn');
                    }, 1000);
                }, 1000);
            }, 1000);
        }, 1000);
    }, 1000);
}, 1000);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: no code? maybe this should be tagged [homework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/homework).

Comment: Not a student. I can write in some junk coffeescript code attempt (I'm new to the syntax and not enjoying it much yet), but I'm not sure how that proves anything. If you'd like to walk me through it / teach me though, I'm all ears.

Comment: @jaacob: I'm not so good at browser stuff, but I know coffee and JS pretty well. Could you post it as javascript?

Comment: @thejh: sorry for the delay, had some health issues this week. js added in the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than setting a timeout each time, you should try using an interval that fires the same callback until you've reached the end. Take a look at this example, then add in your extra bits for animating.

```
words = ["hey", "just", "testing", "this", "out"]
i = 0
len = words.length

callback = ->
    clearInterval timer if i is len - 1
    console.log words[i]
    i++
    return

timer = setInterval callback, 1000
```

Just for clarity's sake, here is the compiled JS

```
(function() {
  var callback, i, len, timer, words;
  words = ["hey", "just", "testing", "this", "out"];
  i = 0;
  len = words.length;

  callback = function() {
    if (i === len - 1) clearInterval(timer);
    console.log(words[i]);
    i++;
  };

  timer = setInterval(callback, 1000);
}).call(this);
```